# "Illegal instruction: 4" when trying to start Python with virtualenv in OS X

Tags: macos, python-2.7, virtualenv

I've been using Python 2.7.10 in a `virtualenv` environment for a couple of months.

Yesterday, activating the environment went fine, but today suddently I get this cryptic error when trying to start Python from Terminal:

`Illegal instruction: 4`

I have made no changes to my environment (AFAIK), so I'm having a difficult time trying to come to terms with what this error is and what caused it.

Python works fine outside of this `virtualenv` environment. When running via `/usr/local/bin` it presents no problem.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but that's the same crash you'd get if you bundled an executable within a Sandboxed OSX app and attempted to run the executable directly from the command line...

Comment: In this newer similar question, a solution is suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48710094/5802289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem a number of times now. While I can't say for certain what the actual issue is, I believe it basically means that some file(s) in the `virtualenv` installment of Python have become corrupted.

I keep my virtual environment in a synced Dropbox folder, so that may be a large contributor to the issue.

Restoring the virtual environment from a back-up archive worked for me. Or simply reinstall an identical virtual environment.

- First, try activating the faulty environment by `cd <path/to/old_env>` and `source /bin/activate`.
- If it's successfully activated, `cd` to an accessible location on the drive and run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to export a list of currently installed Python modules.
- Delete the old environment.
- Install a new virtual environment of the latest version of Python 2 that you have on the computer, via `virtualenv <path/new_env>`
- Or, if you want to use a specific Python version, first make sure you have you have it on your drive, and then do `virtualenv -p <path>`. Assuming that you have downloaded the Python version with Homebrew, e.g.: `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.6 <path/new_env>`
- Activate the virtual environment via `cd <path/new_env>` and then do `source /bin/activate`.
- Assuming that you kept a list of modules to reinstall by previously doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, `cd` to the folder where the text file is located and do `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
- Otherwise, reinstall the modules with `pip` manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and found solution by uninstalling psycopg2 and installing older version. As I understood my comp was not supporting some commands in new version